# Load preliminary results, then reload when completed (Django or ajax)

Tags: ajax, django

I have a page that is taking far too long to load, because it requires 50+ objects to be fetched from the database.
I would like to load the page with only, say, the first 10 results, then let the server get on with loading the rest in the background, and then refresh the page.

Is there a way of doing something like:

```
def foo_view(request):
    values = Foo.objects.all()[:10]
    render_to_response(template, values, context_instance=...)
    values = Foo.objects.all()
    return render_to_response(template, values, context_instance=...)
```

Or is this a job for ajax? (Reloading the data as soon as the page has loaded.)

Thanks!

**Edit:**

It turns out that I was mistaken about the cause of the long loading time: actually fetching 50-100 objects from the database barely causes a delay.
There was a method in my template that resulted in n^3 database hits for my n items, when I should have been calling it once in the view function, and passing the results to my template.

Comment: AJAX is the way to go, you could use celery tasks or some cache backend to speed up things depending on what you need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AJAX is your solution. Add first 10 objects to your page. Then if user scrolls down fetch another 10 and so on. Like twitter. Or use pagination ? :)

Comment: I may well end up using the ajax-scrolling solution if the number of objects increases, thanks. Unfortunately, that will only work for unsorted objects, I believe? Since sorting them requires accessing them all regardless.